# how to install k nearest neighbour in R

Tags: r, installation

There used to be a package called knnflex for language R, but it is not any longer available from CRAN. I have got the tar files, but how I can install it under R?
also is there any other package that can support knn.dist or knn.predict?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Package **FNN**. A collection of fast k-nearest neighbor search algorithms and applications including a cover-tree, kd-tree and the nearest neighbor algorithm in package class. In addition, KNN classification, regression and information measures are also implemented.

See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am using RStudio 0.98.994 and to install the knn package just one command is enough which is **install.packages(class)** and to load the same class type **library(class)**. Hope it helps.

Comment: The correct syntax should be ``install.packages("NameOfPackage", dependencies = TRUE)``.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/utils/html/INSTALL.html